# Database drop-down list in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

Can some one please let me know how to get to this dialog in Qlikview document?

[image]

I am reading the book Qlikview for Developers cookbook, page 228. But could not figure out. The exact sentence there is

**Create a new QlikView document. Set the Database drop-down list to OLEDB and click
on Connect.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qlikview Press control+E ... you will see it in the bottom of the newly opened window (script window)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First open the script

File Menu > Edit Script

At the bottom of this screen is the data tab, underneath database, select OLE DB from the drop down and press connect.

Comment: Also, check out my blog post on [connecting to SQL Server](http://oneqlikatatime.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-connect-to-sql-server.html)